# Soporte sin conexion en FIRESTORE

Tags: java, firebase, firestore

Quiero hacer una app de recolección de datos en campo para android; hice una pero con [sqlite](/questions/tagged/sqlite), pero es incomodo recoger los archivos `.db` que genera la app (hice que el archivo `.db` se muestre en descargas y asi hacer una copia manual por parte el usuario).

Estuve leyendo la documentación de FIRESTORE y esta da soporte sin conexión, si en youtube hay muchos crud de firestore pero no mencionan esos beneficios, hay que hacer algo en especial para obtener esa funcion?

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
    .setPersistenceEnabled(true)
    .build();
```

db.setFirestoreSettings(settings);

en la documentacion dice que para android y apple ya esta habilitada por defecto.